# Proper way to detect SQLCMD running in the machine - WIX installer Pre-requisite

Tags: c#, wix

I am writing a custom action to use a pre-requite to detect if SQLCMD is working on the machine. I can check if there is SQLCMD on the machine by using code below.

In the installer we use CMDPrompt to do stuff with SQLCMD, but if the machine doesnt have SQLCMD path in environment variables it will not work. But i would also want to know why CMDprompt gives `'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command error`.

```
[CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult FindSqlCMD(Session session)
        {
            DebugMsg(session, "Start FindSqlCMD");
            string[] sqlVersions = session["SQLVERSIONS"].Split(';');

            List<RegistryKey> sqlKeys = new List<RegistryKey>();

            var sqlDacPaths = new string[] { "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\{0}\\DAC\\bin", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\{0}\\DAC\\bin" };

            var sqlPackageName = "SqlPackage.exe";

            foreach (string SqlVersion in sqlVersions)
            {


                foreach (var sqlDacPath in sqlDacPaths)
                {
                    var path = string.Format(sqlDacPath, SqlVersion);



                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {

                        var sqlPackagePath = Path.Combine(path, sqlPackageName);

                        if (File.Exists(sqlPackagePath))
                        {


                            session["SQLBINDIR"] = sqlPackagePath;
                            return ActionResult.Success;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            DebugMsg(session, string.Format("Didn't find any SQL DAC SQLPackage"));

            session.Log("End FindSqlCMD");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better try to avoid `exe` custom actions as much as possible. The possible solution is find sqlcmd via WiX:

```
 <!-- Find sqlcmd.exe path  -->
<Property Id="SQLBINDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir11x64" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir10x64" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir90x64" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir11" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir10" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir90" 
                  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup" 
                  Name="Path" 
                  Type="raw" />

</Property>
```

After that you can run it

```
 <CustomAction Id="sqlcmd.cmd" 
              Property="sqlcmd" 
              Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]sqlcmd.exe&quot; -E -S $(var.serverinstance) -V 1 -i &quot;$(var.inputfile)&quot; -o &quot;$(var.outputfile)&quot;" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.But there are times were SQLCMD is in the machine but cant run in CMDPrompt because the SQLCMD path is not set in environment variables .How to handle that in WIX installer.

Comment: I am doing something like this
 var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE";  StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                var process = Process.Start(StartInfo);
                process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode == 9009)
 {
 session.Message(InstallMessage.Error + (int)MessageBoxIcon.Error + (int)MessageBoxButtons.OK, new Record { FormatString = "'SQLCMD' is not recognized as an internal or external command" });
                    return ActionResult.Failure;
                }